# Install React Unsupported Engine, React

Tags: reactjs, npm

Hi I have clone a project from git hub. Then try

```
npm install
```

got an error

> C:\React\React_latest\React>npm install npm WARN EBADENGINE
> Unsupported engine { npm WARN EBADENGINE   package:
> 'datasource@0.0.1', npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.8.x' },
> npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.14.0', npm: '8.3.1' } npm
> WARN EBADENGINE } npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { npm WARN
> EBADENGINE   package: 'react-side-bar@1.0.4', npm WARN EBADENGINE
> required: { node: '12.x', npm: '6.x' }, npm WARN EBADENGINE   current:
> { node: 'v16.14.0', npm: '8.3.1' } npm WARN EBADENGINE } npm ERR! code
> ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT npm ERR! network Socket timeout npm ERR! network
> This is a problem related to network connectivity. npm ERR! network In
> most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings. npm
> ERR! network npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make
> sure that the npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See:
> 'npm help config'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's possible this is related to your npm version. Did you recently change versions, or forget perhaps to use nvm to force the nodeJS version you wanted?

Comment: this may be a network problem `npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT npm ERR!`  this is the reason,